# md-elevation stopped working?

Tags: angular, material-design, elevation

A few weeks ago I was using

```
class="md-elevation-z10"
```

But recently is seems it doesn't work anymore. Everywhere that I use it in the app stopped showing elevations.

Did something recently change to make md-elevation-z# stop working? I can't seem to find anything documented or on Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [**Changelog.md**](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-from-beta1) Breaking Changes

> Styling is no longer prefixed by `md-`. All styling is now prefixed by
>   `mat-` so that apps can upgrade from AngularJS Material to Angular
>   Material without styling conflicts between the two library components.

This change has been introduced in beta.1 version. So you should be using `mat-` prefix instead of `md-` going forward.

```
class="mat-elevation-z10"
```